# Exception slipping exception handler

Tags: php, exception

I got the following exception in my page:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function someFunction() on a
    non-object in seomfile.php on line 15
```

My code near line 15 is:

```
try
{
    return getObject()->someFunction(); // line 15
}
catch(Exception $e) { }
```

I know `getObject()` returns null, but why isn't the `try` block catching it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP mixes Exceptions and Errors. You could use [set_error_handler()](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) to [throw an exception on error](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php).

Comment: No (not as far as I know), that's why they added Exceptions. But with set_error_handler() you can "translate" errors into exceptions.

Comment: @Dani What this does is it allows you to write set your own error handler. So within this error handler you could throw your own Exception, ie: you could turn errors into Exceptions.

Comment: This does not work for all *fatal errors* though ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Jr03R2)), see as well [Calling to static methods for unknown classes doesn't trigger an exception catch in __autoload](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9190809/367456).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use something like this:

```
try {
    $object = getObject();
    If (!is_object($object)) {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    return $object->someFunction();
catch (Exception $e) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's not an exception, it's a standard old-fashioned error.